# Macro to skip blank cells and finishes (Button to send emails)

Tags: excel, vba, sendmail, skip

I have a problem with a macro that I'm using to send emails automatically with a button ... I'm not an expert, so I am looking for your help  (this drives me crazy ... and btw I speak spanish)

The macro is the following:

```
Sub Enviar_Correo2()
'
' Enviar_Correo2
' Enviar por correo electrónico automáticamente el resumen ejecutivo del trabajo de los Equipos de Mejora Continua
'Seleccionamos el rango de celdas a enviar Select

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Resumen ejecutivo").Range("$A$1:$K$52").Select
For I = 1 To 10
'El valor de i se pone en la celda F18 para que con BUSCARV se devuelvan
'los datos correspondientes al ID.
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Configuraciones iniciales").Range("F18").Value = I
'Mostramos la sección para enviar correo.
ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
'Llamamos al envío...
With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
.Item.To = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Configuraciones iniciales").Range("$B$19").Value
'.Item.cc = "correo1@dominio.com" 'con copia a...
'.Item.bcc = "correo2@dominio.com" 'con copia oculta a...
.Item.Subject = "PROPUESTA DE TEMAS PARA APROBACIÓN GERENCIAL"
.Introduction = "Estimados Srs.: Por medio de la presente nos permitimos plantear a Ustedes los siguientes tres temas seleccionados por nuestro Equipo de Mejora Continua, con la finalidad que nos asignen uno para iniciar su estudio. Estamos seguros que el trabajo a realizar sera un aporte valioso para nuestra empresa."
.Item.Send
End With
Next I
End Sub
```

> In this macro, I want to send a range of cells from a sheet "Resumen ejecutivo" to maximum 10 emails localized in another sheet called "Configuraciones iniciales" . The problem is when the user not fill all the column, that is numbered from 1 to 10. I mean not fill the table with 10 emails. If this does not happen, in the last email, the macro is repeated as many times, until 10 emails are completed or as if it were to be sent to 10 emails. I hope you can understand me.

So I want to put a statement in somewhere of this macro to skip blank cells without email addresses in the column numbered from 1 to 10 and finish the action of sending emails.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps trim and check the value 'Item.To' before sending the email.

Comment: Thank you so much! I reviewed with your answers and now the macro works ! :D

Answer (score 0):

I found it difficult to make sense of your code. Here is the sense I made. Please read my comments. They qwere written without the benefit of understanding those already existing in the code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Enviar_Correo2()
    ' Enviar_Correo2
    ' Enviar por correo electrónico automáticamente el resumen ejecutivo del trabajo
    ' de los Equipos de Mejora Continua

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Recipient As String

    ' Seleccionamos el rango de celdas a enviar Select
    ' it's not clear why this range is being selected
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Resumen ejecutivo").Range("$A$1:$K$52").Select

    For i = 0 To 9
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Configuraciones iniciales")
            ' assign the value of B19 to B28 as recipient
            Recipient = Trim(.Cells(19 + i, "B").Value)
            ' skip the following if the cell is blank
            If Len(Recipient) Then
                ' El valor de i se pone en la celda F18 para que con BUSCARV
                ' se devuelvan los datos correspondientes al ID.
                ' not clear why you would want to write a different number to the
                ' same cell on each loop
                .Range("F18").Value = i + 1

                'Mostramos la sección para enviar correo.
                ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
                'Llamamos al envío...
                With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
                    .Item.To = Recipient
                    '.Item.cc = "correo1@dominio.com" 'con copia a...
                    '.Item.bcc = "correo2@dominio.com" 'con copia oculta a...
                    .Item.Subject = "PROPUESTA DE TEMAS PARA APROBACIÓN GERENCIAL"
                    .Introduction = "Estimados Srs.: Por medio de la presente nos permitimos plantear " & _
                                    "a Ustedes los siguientes tres temas seleccionados por nuestro " & _
                                    "Equipo de Mejora Continua, con la finalidad que nos asignen uno " & _
                                    "para iniciar su estudio. Estamos seguros que el trabajo a realizar " & _
                                    "sera un aporte valioso para nuestra empresa."
                    .Item.Send
                End With
            End If
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

I think the above code should be not worse than the original but it might contain some thoughts that help you build what you really want.

Comment: Thank you so much! I reviewed with your answers and now the macro works ! :D